# Foundry scripts read deployed contract addresses

Tags: solidity, foundry

I deployed with one script contract and I wonder there is a way to read that deployment from foundry env and its data like contract address to use it in another script?

I managed to do below with this cheatcodes
https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/parse-json

```js
contract CheckScript is Script {
    function run() external returns (Tx1559 memory) {
        uint256 deployerPrivateKey = vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY");
        vm.startBroadcast(deployerPrivateKey);
        ITH404 th = ITH404(0xc5D38Bcc8E0B8a7C61bef5b1cc8945118a0Fd712);

        string memory root = vm.projectRoot();
        string memory path = string.concat(
            root,
            "/broadcast/deploy.sol/666666666/run-latest.json"
        );

        Tx1559[] memory transactions = readTx1559s(path);

        console.log(transactions[0].contractAddress);
        vm.stopBroadcast();

        return transactions[0];
    }
}
```

but in the end all I get is this error

script failed:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Storing and reading as `environment` variables:

One way is to store the details corresponding to a particular contract in `.env` file as environment variables, and later access them in other scripts.

Here’s a sample code to achieve the same:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {NFT} from "../src/NFT.sol";

contract NFTScript is Script {
    function run() public {
        vm.startBroadcast(vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY"));
        NFT nft = new NFT("NonFun", "NFT");
        vm.stopBroadcast();

        // Store the contract address in an environment variable
        vm.envSet("NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS", address(nft));
    }
}
```

Then, access the `NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS` in another script:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";

contract AnotherScript is Script {
    function run() public {
        // Read the contract address from the environment variable
        address nftContractAddress = vm.envAddress("NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS");

        // Use the contract address as needed
        // For example, interact with the NFT contract
    }
}
```

---

### Reading from `broadcast` folder:

To read the files in your script, you need to add this line into your `foundry.toml`, granting access to read files:

```js
fs_permissions = [{ access = "read", path = "./" }]
```

Then, the script goes as follows:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {console} from "forge-std/console.sol";
import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {stdJson} from "forge-std/StdJson.sol";

contract CheckScript is Script {
    function run() external view {
        string memory root = vm.projectRoot();
        string memory path = string.concat(
            root,
            "/broadcast/deploy.sol/666666666/run-latest.json"
        );
        string memory json = vm.readFile(path);
        bytes memory contractName = stdJson.parseRaw(
            json,
            ".transactions[0].contractName"
        );
        bytes memory contractAddress = stdJson.parseRaw(
            json,
            ".transactions[0].contractAddress"
        );
        bytes memory transactionHash = stdJson.parseRaw(
            json,
            ".receipts[0].transactionHash"
        );

        console.log(string(contractName));
        console.logAddress(bytesToAddress(contractAddress));
        console.logBytes(transactionHash);
    }

    function bytesToAddress(
        bytes memory bys
    ) private pure returns (address addr) {
        assembly {
            addr := mload(add(bys, 32))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice example, the problem is that this is only available for that session, so if you need to reuse it, like for example read data from a contract this is no use, we just need to HC address into the script or in .env